# Install AWS command line tools on a AWS instance via chef

Tags: chef-infra

I want to install all AWS command line tools on a AWS instance via chef. Is there any cookbook that I can use directly for doing this.

Comment: Did you try Google ? I tried, 1st result forward me to the cookbook you want... https://github.com/shlomoswidler/awscli

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specifically mention OpsWorks, but in case you are using OpsWorks and not just Chef directly - to do this in OpsWorks you simply edit the Recipes for your Layer and add awscli under OS Packages.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, there is an awscli cookbook. You can also install them through your distro's package manager with just a `package` resource.